# Firebase authentication does not work after publishing

Tags: firebase, sha1

After publishing the application i cannot use firebase authentication i get an error saying : this app is not authorized to use firebaseauthentication check sha1 or package name

I went and got the sha1 that is in the jks file and added it to firebase but the problem remains what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating the app bundle after adding the SHA1 to firebase thanks